# How to make a bash find run in same process?

Tags: bash, find

Code first

```
echo $$ - $BASHPID

find . | while read -r file; do
    echo $$ - $BASHPID: ${file}
done
```

The problem is the code in `while` is running in a sub process. How can I make this run in the same process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
echo "$$ - $BASHPID"

while read -r file; do
    echo "$$ - $BASHPID: ${file}" #better to quote!
done < <(find .)
# -----^^^^^^^^^
```

From the given link:

> Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or
>   output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary
>   file.