# How to make the permission of files on linux of group same to owner?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, file-permissions

How can I recursive change the permissions of files/directories to become group permissions the same as owner permissions?

e.g.
Before:

```
640 x.txt
744 y
400 y/z.txt
```

After:

```
660 x.txt
774 y
440 y/z.txt
```

Thanks to fedorqui got created this as answer:

```
find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for file; do 
perm=$(stat -c '%a' "$file")
new_perm=$(sed -r "s/^(.)./\1\1/" <<< "$perm")
chmod "$new_perm" "$file";
done'
```

Comment: If you always want to keep the user and group permissions the same, a helpful start is altering your umask: `umask 002`

Answer (score 4):

Using `stat` you can get the permissions of a file.

For example:

```
$ touch a
$ stat -c '%a' a
644
```

Then, if we catch this value, we can use `sed` to make the 2nd field have the same value as the 1st:

```
$ sed -r "s/^(.)./\1\1/" <<< "644"
664
```

And then we are ready to say

```
chmod 664 file
```

Now that we have all the pieces, see how can we glue them together. The idea is to catch the first character of the `stat` output to generate the new value:

```
perm=$(stat -c '%a' file)
new_perm=$(sed -r "s/^(.)./\1\1/" <<< "$perm")
chmod "$new_perm" file
```

Then, it is a matter of looping through the files and doing this:

```
for file in pattern/*; do
   perm=$(stat -c '%a' "$file")
   new_perm=$(sed -r "s/^(.)./\1\1/" <<< "$perm")
   chmod "$new_perm" "$file"
 done
```

If you want this to be fed by a `find` result as you indicate in comments and your updated question, you can use a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854):

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
   perm=$(stat -c '%a' "$file")
   new_perm=$(sed -r "s/^(.)./\1\1/" <<< "$perm")
   chmod "$new_perm" "$file";
done < <(find . -name '*' -print0)
```

Comment: Thanks, only missing part is recursivity :-)

Comment: @wdk there is a beautiful `for` loop that can do this if you are in two levels. Otherwise, and if this contains way more levels, you can use `find` through a process substitution.

Comment: @wdk updated with a `find` approach, since the way you use it in the updated question is a bit overkilling.