# Is it possible to use "test" before "while read" in pipeline?

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipeline

I have pipeline like that:

```
pipeline | test $number -eq 3 && while read A B C D; do...; done
```

But that doesn't work because `while read` can't read arguments from pipeline anymore bec of `test $number -eq 3 &&`

How can I solve that? I musn't use awk or sed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854):

```
test $number -eq 3 && while read A B C D;
do
    ...
done < <(pipeline)
```

For example:

```
$ n=3
$ test $n -eq 3 && while read A B C; do echo "A: $A, B: $B, rest: $C --"; done < <(echo a b c d e f)
A: a, B: b, rest: c d e f --
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the clearest way to write your code would be to use an `if`:

```
if test $number -eq 3; then
    pipeline | while read A B C D; do...; done
fi
```

If you really want to use `&&`, then I guess you can use this:

```
test $number -eq 3 && pipeline | while read A B C D; do...; done
```

...but personally I don't think it's as clear.

Comment: I would tend to agree, unless the `do...` in the example changes the value of `$number`, in which case the conditional would be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `seq 20 | paste - - - -` as your "pipeline" to generate some lines with 4 words per line.

Here's your problem:

```
$ seq 20 | paste - - - - | test $number -eq 3 && while read A B C D; do echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C D=$D"; done
^C
```

The while loop is stuck waiting for input on stdin.

This fix just groups the test and loop together, so `read` can access the pipeline's output:

```
$ seq 20 | paste - - - - | { test $number -eq 3 && while read A B C D; do echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C D=$D"; done; }
A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4
A=5 B=6 C=7 D=8
A=9 B=10 C=11 D=12
A=13 B=14 C=15 D=16
A=17 B=18 C=19 D=20
```