# how to check for the presence of two words in a file using GREP

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, grep

I have two files A.txt and B.txt containing two lists respectively as shown bellow.

File A.txt

```
hello
hi 
ko
```

File B.txt

```
fine
No 
And how
why
```

Now I want to check presence of any of these words (from A.txt AND B.txt) in a line in another file C.txt.

I am using the grep command

```
grep -iof A.txt C.txt| grep B.txt
```

C.txt contains sentences containing words from A.txt and B.txt

```
Hello I am fine
I am not fine
why ko is and how?
```

doesn't show any output

So, now I want if any word from A.txt and B.txt present simultaneously in one sentence it should show the output as

```
Hello fine
why ko and how
```

To print only the matching words from both files if they occur simultaneously in C.txt, instead of printing the whole line from C.txt

Comment: You say *presence of **either** of these words*. I'm not sure whether I understand *either* in this context. You mean *presence of **any** of these words*, don't you? I.e. you want to know whether there is a line in C.txt, which contains either a word from A.txt or from B.txt. Correct?

Comment: I just edited the question. I meant presence of any of these words from A.txt and B.txt occuring simultaneously in C.txt

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by *simultaneously* in this case, but since you have accepted an answer, I guess this is what you were looking for.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to say:

```
$ grep -if B <(grep -if A C)
Hello I am fine
why ko is and how?
```

This uses `-f` to provide the expressions. It can be a file... or a file you create on the fly with the [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854) `<( ... )`.

Firstly, `grep -if A C` matches all the words in `C` that are in `A`:

```
$ grep -if A C
Hello I am fine        # "Hello" highlighted
why ko is and how?     # "ko" highlighted
```

Then, its output is compared with the content in `B`.

```
$ grep -if B <(grep -if A C)
Hello I am fine        # "fine" highlighted
why ko is and how?     # "and how" highlighted
```

Depending on your needs, you may want to add `-F`, `-w` and `-i`.

From `man grep`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)

   -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore  case  distinctions  in  both  the  PATTERN and the input
          files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)

   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

Comment: where am I mentioning the two files here?

Comment: I think it should be - for the safe side - `fgrep`, not `grep` - just in case that one of the pattern files contains characters such as a period or $. Another problem is that the OP wants to match *words*, not strings. Grepping for, i.e., 'hi', would also match for instance 'hint', which is probably not what the OP wanted. In any case, I think the problem should be specified more precisely before we can propose a solution.

Comment: I just edited, main aim is to find presence of any of the words from A.txt and B.txt occuring simultaneously in C.txt

Comment: @Doej see my update with `$ grep -f B <(grep -if A C)`.

Comment: @user1934428 good point. I added (or suggested) `-F`, `-i`, `-w`.