# Loop through filenames with numbers in alphanumeric order for OSX terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

In OSX terminal, how do we loop through files, that start with a number, in alphanumeric order?

I have this bash script, so far, which loops through files in no apparent order:

```
FILES=/Users/somefolder/*.txt
    for f in $FILES
do
    echo $f
done
```

Also, my files start with a number, for example, when I use the `-v` switch in `ls`, they are listed as:

```
10_file.txt 
11_file.txt
21_file.txt 
2_file.txt
```

However, I want the order to be: `2_file.txt`, `10_file.txt`, `11_file.txt` and `21_file.txt`

Comment: The other should be alphabetical: [Does bash's * match files in alphanumeric order?](http://superuser.com/a/192288/204979). At least in GNU Bash

Comment: My files start with a number  `10_file.txt` appears before `2_file.txt`, obviously sorting by characters in filename. I will adjust my question now.

Comment: Well, this means that it is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Then alphabetical sorting is not what I am looking for. Is it alphanumeric sorting? Is there a name for this?

Comment: Yes. From the link in the link I posted, _Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an alphabetical sort. From [Bash Reference Manual # 3.5.8. Filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> 3.5.8 Filename Expansion
>
> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set (see The Set
>   Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.
>   If one of these characters appears, then **the word is regarded as a
>   pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames
>   matching the pattern.**

To get a numerical sorting, use a `while` loop that gets fed by the result of  `find`, which you can sort numerically:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   echo "$file --"
done < <(find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort -n)
```

That is:

- `find /your/path -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f`

  Gets elements in `/your/path` that are a file without going through subdirectories.
- `printf "%f"`

  Prints just the name of the file.
- `sort -n`

  Sorts numerically
- `while ... do; ... done < <(command)`

  Is a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854) that injects its output in the `while` loop.

Comment: You properly want `-mindepth 1` as well - or `-type f` if files only - to avoid current directory.

Comment: @andlrc true, good point about `mindepth`. I just updated to explain this better. Thanks