# How to find users connected to the server in the last 24 hours?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I want this:

```
sojjan   pts/9        localhost        Thu Oct 13 08:04:14 2016 - Thu Oct 13 08:04:15 2016  (00:00)    
gurra    pts/9        localhost        Wed Oct 12 15:36:00 2016 - Wed Oct 12 15:36:02 2016  (00:00)    
sojjan   pts/8        :0               Wed Oct 12 10:13:34 2016   still logged in                      
sojjan   pts/7        :0               Mon Oct 10 13:34:56 2016   still logged in
```

To become like this:

```
Last 24h SSH logins:

sojjan   pts/9        localhost        Thu Oct 13 08:04:14 2016 - Thu Oct 13 08:04:15 2016  (00:00)    
gurra    pts/9        localhost        Wed Oct 12 15:36:00 2016 - Wed Oct 12 15:36:02 2016  (00:00)    

Still logged in:

sojjan   pts/8        :0               Wed Oct 12 10:13:34 2016   still logged in                      
sojjan   pts/7        :0               Mon Oct 10 13:34:56 2016   still logged in
```

I tried as

```
#!/bin/bash

test0=$(last -F | grep still)
test1=$(date | awk {'print $2, $3'});
test2=$(date --date='-1 days' | awk {'print $2, $3'});

last -F | grep -v 'reboot' | grep -i "$test0\|$test1\|$test2"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a handy parameter in the `last` command:

> **-t** YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
>
> Display the state of logins as of the specified time.  This is useful,  e.g.,  to  determine  easily  who  was logged in at a particular time -- specify that time with -t and look for "still logged in".

With this, we can get `last` command from 24 hours ago and compare it with now using [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854):

```
diff <(last) <(last -t "$(date -d"1 day ago" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")")
```

Then, it is a matter of parsing this output, which you can do with `awk`:

```
awk '/still logged in\s*$/ {logged[NR]=$0; next} # store logged
     {finished[NR]=$0}                           # store finished
     END {print "Last 24h SSH logins:";          # print header finished
     for (i in finished)                         # print finished
         print finished[i];
     printf "\nStill logged in:\n";              # print header logged
     for (i in logged)                           # print logged
         print logged[i]}'
```

All together, and as a one-liner, you have something like:

```
diff <(last) <(last -t "$(date -d"1 day ago" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")") | awk '/still logged in\s*$/ {logged[NR]=$0; next} {finished[NR]=$0} END {print "Last 24h SSH logins:"; for (i in finished) print finished[i]; printf "\nStill logged in:\n"; for (i in logged) print logged[i]}'
```

Comment: Thanks Mustafa and fedorqui. Im so new to this.

Comment: But i don't know how to get that info to a working script. heee

Comment: @Larsvontrierpung then you have to do some research yourself. We are not here to spoon feed you, but to help. Try it out and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
lastday=$(date --date='-1 days' | awk {'print $2, $3'});

echo -e "Last 24h SSH logins:\n"
last -F | grep -v 'reboot' | grep -i "$lastday"

echo -e "\nStill logged in:\n"
last -F | grep -v 'reboot' | grep -i "still"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well now!

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
lastday=$(date --date='-1 days' | awk '{ print $2, $3 }'|sed 's/ \([1-9]\)$/  \1/')

echo "lastday $lastday"
echo




echo -e "\nLast 24h SSH logins:"
last -F | grep -v 'reboot' | grep "$lastday" | grep -v "still logged in"

echo -e "\nStill logged in:"
last -F | grep -v 'reboot' | grep "still logged in"
```

Comment: do you know you can use `date "+...<things>..."` to have your desired format of the date, instead of parsing its default output? See my answer.