# Removing list of comma separated words from a sentence

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have two variables as follows :

```
sentence="name string,age int,address string,dob timestamp,job string"
ignore="age int,dob timestamp"
```

Basically I need to iterate through the comma separated variable `$ignore` and remove each word from the above varibale `$sentence`.

After performing this the output sentence should be as below:

```
echo $outputsentence
name string,address string,job string
```

Should I create an array for words to be ignored and iterate through it an perform a sed operation? Is there any other way around?

Comment: Can you show us the shell code you have tried?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation that requires sets: you want to know which members of set A are not present in set B.

For this we have a beautiful article [Set Operations in the Unix Shell](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/) that describes all of them.

If you want to check the intersection of sets, say:

```
$ comm -12 <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$sentence" | sort) <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$ignore" | sort)
age int
dob timestamp
```

For complement, use `comm -23`:

```
$ comm -23 <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$sentence" | sort) <(tr ',' '\n' <<< "$ignore" | sort)
address string
job string
name string
```

Note `tr ',' '\n' <<< "$var" | sort` just splits the `,`-separated strings in slices. Then, `<( )` is a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870094/1983854).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
pattern=$(sed "s/,/|/g" <<< "$ignore")
outputsentence=$(sed -r 's/('"$pattern"'),*//g' <<< "$sentence")
```

The first sed command replace all `,` with an alternation operator `|` in the ignore list.

This result is used as a pattern in to remove the strings from `$sentence`.